# How to decompose a matrix into an antisymmetric matrix plus a multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I was given a problem to solve earlier that I couldn't figure out.  I don't still have it, but it was basically: **Given the invertible matrix $A$, find the invertible matrix $P$, such that $A=P^{-1}CP$**.  Where $$C=\begin{bmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c\end{bmatrix}$$ and $A$ I don't exactly remember, but it was something like $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I was completely stumped.  I see that $A$ and $C$ are similar so they should have the same determinant and trace.  So I should be able to find $C$ from that.  But how would I find $P$?

And I can see that this is similar to eigendecomposition, but is this decomposition at all useful, or did some textbook writer just come up with this problem with no underlying use?

Comment: Your $C$ is not "antisymmetric" by the usual definition; we only have $C = -C^T$ if $c =0$.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Right.  Is there a name for this type of matrix?

Comment: not as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If two matrices are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues, then they are similar.

If an $n \times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, it is necessarily diagonalizable.

The punchline: you should try to find a matrix $C$ that has the same eigenvalues as $A$.

---

Note that if we have invertible matrices $S,T$ such that
$$
SCS^{-1} = D = TAT^{-1}
$$
then
$$
A = T^{-1}SCS^{-1}T = (S^{-1}T)C(S^{-1}T)
$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I can find $C$ because I can find the determinant and trace of $A$.  Then I can set $\operatorname{tr}(C)=\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $\det(C)=\det(A)$ and solve the system of equations.  It's $P$ that I couldn't figure out how to find.

Comment: see my edit ${}$

Comment: I should have thought of that.  Thanks @Omnomnomnom.